wxWidget frame / window not closing
I have been developing a custom UI for Autodesk Alias. I use wxwidget for this.
i follow youtube tutorials and made a window / frame.
i have problem now. when i click the close button in menubar ,the frame/window is not closing. on clicking the close button i am getting  a log,but the window is not closing. The window is getting closed only when i remove the plugin from Alias.  i Shared the code below. any help would be highly appreciated.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <AlUniverse.h>
#include <AlFunctionHandle.h>
#include <AlFunction.h>
#include <AlLiveData.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "GUI_App.h"
#include "MainFrame.h"

static AlMomentaryFunction hFunc;
static AlFunctionHandle handle;

// Implement the wxWidgets application class

// Function to launch the wxWidgets GUI
void LaunchGUI() {
    AlPrintf(kPrompt, "inside Launch");
    // Check if the application instance already exists
    if (!wxTheApp) {
        wxApp::SetInstance(new GUI_App());

        int argc = 0;
        char** argv = nullptr;
        wxEntryStart(argc, argv);
        wxTheApp->CallOnInit();
    }
}

// This function will be called when the plugin icon is clicked
void test() {
    LaunchGUI();
}

extern "C" PLUGINAPI_DECL int plugin_init(const char* dirName) {
    AlUniverse::initialize();
    hFunc.create("test", test); // AlMomentary Function Name
    handle.create("PlayGround", &hFunc); // AlFunction Handle
    handle.setAttributeString("New Plugin features are tested here");
    handle.appendToMenu("ma_layers");
    AlPrintf(kPrompt, "!!PluginStarted!!");
    return 0;
}

extern "C" PLUGINAPI_DECL int plugin_exit(void) {
    // remove functionhandle from menu
    handle.removeFromMenu();
    handle.deleteObject();    // delete functionhandle obj
    hFunc.deleteObject(); // momentary function

    // Clean up wxWidgets
    if (wxTheApp) {
        wxTheApp->OnExit();
        wxEntryCleanup();
    }

    return 0;
}

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "GUI_App.h"
#include "MainFrame.h"

#include <AlUniverse.h>
#include <AlLiveData.h>

wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(GUI_App);

bool GUI_App::OnInit()
{
    AlPrintf(kPrompt, "oninit");

    MainFrame* mainFrame = new MainFrame("To Do List");

    mainFrame->Show();
    return true;
}

#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this);
    wxButton* button = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, "btn", wxPoint(150, 50), wxSize(100, 35));
    wxCheckBox* checkbox = new wxCheckBox(panel, wxID_ANY, "checkbox", wxPoint(550, 55));
    wxStaticText* textbox = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "SomeText Conmes here", wxPoint(120, 155));
    wxTextCtrl* texteditbox = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, "Text Editable", wxPoint(500, 155), wxSize(200, -1));

    button->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainFrame::OnButtonClicked, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, &MainFrame::OnCloseWindow, this);

    CreateStatusBar();
}

void MainFrame::OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& evt) {
    wxLogStatus("btn clicked");
}

void MainFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& evt)
{
    //Iconize(true);
    wxLogStatus("close is clicekd");
    Destroy();
    evt.Skip();
}



Try adding a "Close();" after "wxLogStatus("btn clicked");". And Destroy() is not necessary.

In general, from your code you don't need the OnClose method. Normally you don't clall Destryo() on wxCloseEvent because the event is to skip() or propagate() the event, not actually be taken as "destructor" of your app.

I still dont understand.Should i remove OnClose method?

On using close(), the application is completely crashing down.
